# does anyone know why xampp image issue with html

Tags: html, xampp

Does anyone know why xampp has issues in HTML coding for images for background of the page as I am having issues with it.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Hi Adam.  The problem is probably not xampp but resides deep in the bowels of your code.  Unfortunately you didn't share that with us so we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry but here is the original format.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>YAHUAS</title>

<style>
body {
  background-image: url("Pictures/Yahuas.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="student.php">Student data</a>

</body>
</html>

Comment: When I don't use xampp then it works OK, I have tried with few other students in my class   like using SRC and etc and still no luck

Comment: It works when I don't use xampp

Comment: Make sure xampp can see your file. Show us your directory structure